# svn command-line commands are not working in webpage after publishing at IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, svn, command-line

i am using svn cmd line commands to fetch the top revision number from SVN server in c#.net webpage as below.

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfoSVNorTFS = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe");
processStartInfoSVNorTFS.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfoSVNorTFS.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfoSVNorTFS.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfoSVNorTFS.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process processSVNorTFS = Process.Start(processStartInfoSVNorTFS);
if (processSVNorTFS != null)
{
   process.StandardInput.WriteLine("c:");
   process.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd\\");
   process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd C:\INETPUB\WWWROOT\SlikSvn\bin");       

   processSVNorTFS.StandardInput.WriteLine("svn ls svn://india01/Repo" + svnloc);
        processSVNorTFS.StandardInput.Close(); // line added to stop process from hanging on ReadToEnd()

   SVNorTFS = SVNorTFS + processSVNorTFS.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
   if (svnloc == "/branches")
   {
      SVNorTFS_branches = SVNorTFS;
      //SVNorTFS_branches = processSVNorTFS.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
   }

}
```

This code is working fine in my machine but after publishing it to IIS(V5.1) server it's not working.
is there anything i need to configure for IIS server like sliksvn?
please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Last I knew (and this goes back a lot of years, so it may be outdated), there are major security concerns with executing applications via IIS.

If you're working in .NET code & need to perform SVN operations, you should be using [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/)